# Есть ли метод обратный методу .get для словарей? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, методы, dict

Есть словарь

```
mc_dict = {'полнолуние': 0, 'убывающая Луна': (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7), 'последняя четверть': 4,
           'новолуние': 8, 'растущая Луна': (9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15), 'первая четверть': 12}
```

С помощью метода .get можно узнать значения соответствующие ключу

```
print(mc_dict.get('убывающая Луна'))
>> (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7)
```

И вот вопрос, есть ли метод обратный .get, который возвратит ключ для указанного значения?

```
print(mc_dict.method(11))
>> растущая Луна
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318625/how-to-implement-an-efficient-bidirectional-hash-table

Comment: @KoVadim , спасибо большое. Я так понял в ванильном словарике нет поддержки двунаправленного использования get?

Comment: поиск строится по ключам, а не по значениям.

Comment: Нет, потому что в общем случае это невозможно и не нужно. Что вернуть если у двух разных ключей одинаковое значение? Ну и даже в вашем примере вы получаете ключ не по значению (которое список), а по одному из значений из списка, т.е. очень специфическая задача.

Answer (score 2):

Где-то видел решение красивее, но это тоже рабочее и можно записать в 1 строку.

```
mc_dict = {'полнолуние': 0, 'убывающая Луна': (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7), 'последняя четверть': 4,
           'новолуние': 8, 'растущая Луна': (9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15), 'первая четверть': 12}
find_val = (9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15)
print([i for i in mc_dict.keys()][[i for i in mc_dict.values()].index(find_val)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Простого метода нет, придётся городить однострочник. Тем более, что у вас где-то коллекции, а где-то одиночные значения:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable

mc_dict = {'полнолуние': 0, 'убывающая Луна': (1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7), 'последняя четверть': 4,
           'новолуние': 8, 'растущая Луна': (9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15), 'первая четверть': 12}

n = 11
print([key for key,val in mc_dict.items() \
    if n == val or (isinstance(val, Iterable) and n in val)])
```

Вывод:

```
['растущая Луна']
```